# Parameterization of facelet custom tag

Tags: jsf, facelets

I have created facelet template:

left-right.xhtml

```
<ui:composition>
    <ui:include name="left" />
    <hr />
    <ui:include name="right" />
</ui:composition>
```

After, if I use this template with **ui:decorate** it works fine:

index.xhtml

```
<ui:decorate template="left-right.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="left">FOO</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="right">BAR</ui:define>
</ui:decorate>
```

BUT, if I use this template as custom facelet tag it does not works.

custom-taglib.xml

```
<facelet-taglib>
    <tag>
        <tag-name>leftright</tag-name>
        <source>left-right.xhtml</source>
    </tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

index.xhtml

```
<custom:leftright>
    <ui:define name="left">FOO</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="right">BAR</ui:define>
</custom:leftright>
```

The content inside **ui:define** tags is not included into template :(

So, question is how can I parameterise facelet template if it renders as facelet custom tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(note that you have a syntax error in your `left-right.xhtml`, you should be using `<ui:insert>` instead of `<ui:include>`, but I'll assume it to be just careless oversimplification)*

A tag file cannot be treated as a template client. You need to approach it differently depending on the concrete functional requirement. If you're on JSF 2.x, then a [composite component](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/composite-component/info) would be the closest which you need. You could define the parts as `<f:facet>` and render them by `<cc:renderFacet>` in the composite implementation.

E.g.

`/resources/custom/leftRight.xhtml`

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:facet name="left" required="true" />
    <cc:facet name="right" required="true" />
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <cc:renderFacet name="left" />
    <hr />
    <cc:renderFacet name="right" />
</cc:implementation>
```

Usage:

```
<custom:leftRight>
    <f:facet name="left">FOO</f:facet>
    <f:facet name="right">FOO</f:facet>
</custom:leftRight>
```

But if you're still on JSF 1.x, you cannot create a composite component. You'd need to stick to `<ui:decorate>`.

#### See also:

- [When to use <ui:include>, tag files, composite components and/or custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen)

Comment: since there is tagAttribute, methodParam, what about introducing `o: facet` (same functionality as `renderFacet` so facet can be used with facelet tags?